# Can I use storyboard to embed UINavigationController's view inside a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to keep the top and bottom sections of my view stationary and I only want to add a navigation controller at the center of the screen.

This has been perfectly doable for a lot of years and now as everyone is so enchanted by the Storyboards, I wanted to do the same through the storyboard and it seems like it is impossible.

Is it possible anyways?

Comment: Maybe using ContainerView you can achieve this via storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Container View in the storyboard.

> Container View defines a region within a view controller's view
>   subgraph that can include a child view controller. Create an embed
>   segue from the container view to the child view controller in the
>   storyboard.